# How to update items in combobox when user click on the combobox in Qt

Tags: qt, combobox

I would like to update the items in combobox as user click on it, so when it unfold it will show the latest items. What signal should I connect and use? Thanks.

Comment: For a combobox, user first clicks on it to show the list of items, then make a selection by clicking one. What I want is to update items in the list when user click on the box, before user seeing the items. Yes, usually one would update the combobox as items change, regardless if user clicking it, but in my case, the item list may have changed multiple times and only the last change is meanful to user, so I want combobox item to update only when user clicks on it so it only just update once. activated() signal is only emitted when user choose an item, that is not what I'm looking for

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your question in the first place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mouse press slot for QComboBox - fill the items dynamically if user clicks the combobox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33773368/mouse-press-slot-for-qcombobox-fill-the-items-dynamically-if-user-clicks-the-c)